# Definition of a two state random variable

Tags: stochastic-processes, random-variables, random, bernoulli-distribution

I have a PMF, $P_X(x)$ where $x=1$ with probability $p$ and $x=-1$ with probability $(1-p)$.  Is there a concise way to present this in much the same way as a Bernoulli RV would be presented?

Comment: If your Bernoulli variable, $B$, takes on values $1$ and $0$, then $X = 2B-1$.

Comment: Thanks!  $P_X(x)=p^{(x+1)/2}(1-p)^{(1-x)/2}$